# CKEDITOR eval execution

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, eval

when i put my content into CKEDITOR the eval return this error "Unexpected token < "

this is my code

```
eval('CKEDITOR.instances.'+ckeditorID+'.insertHtml('+text+')');
```

where the content of var text is `<p>More Information<p>`

Solution? Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with CKEDITOR but I would suggest trying without the < in the text and see if that fixes it; if so try escaping them (as &lt;). If not check your ckeditorID variable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval` for this.  Just do:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[ckeditorID].insertHtml(text);
```